# iTunes Match priority between computers and cloud

Tags: itunes, icloud, itunes-match

I've been cleaning up my iTunes song collection, and recently edited all songs that had 'various' in the field for Artist. Two days later, they're back.

Is there a sequence to use to make sure an edited artist, song, genre, etc stays with the song and updates on the other Mac/PC that's tied to the account? Strange that these edits were lost this way.